# Aurelia router navigate & navigateToRoute

Tags: aurelia

In app.ts I am looking to navigate to `home/contract-view/10` on a action. Tried

```
this.router.navigateToRoute(`home/contract-view`, { id: 10}, { absolute: true });
```

fails with `Route home/contract-view not be found`

Another try:

```
this.router.navigate(`#/home/contract-view`, { id: 10});
```

fails with `Route not found: contract-view(…)`
How to achieve this?
App.ts:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
        config.title = 'Contracts Portal';
        config.map([
            { route: ['', 'dummy'], name: 'dummy', moduleId: 'dummy', nav: false, title: 'Dummy', settings: { pos: 'left' } },
            { route: 'home', name: 'home', moduleId: 'home', nav: true, title: 'Home', settings:{pos: 'left', class: 'home' }, auth: true },
        ]);
        this.router = router;    
    }
```

Home.ts:

```
 configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
        config.map([
            { route: ['', 'contract-view/:id'], name: 'contract-view', moduleId: 'contract-view', nav: true, title: 'Contract' },
            { route:  'doc-view/:id', name: 'doc-view', href:'doc-view', moduleId: 'doc-view', nav: true, title: 'Document' },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
        this.router.refreshNavigation();
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have router in 'home' configured with `contract-view/:id`, so you need `this.router.navigate('home/contract-view/10')`. And try to remove `this.router.refreshNavigation()` too

Comment: This could be better with a string interpolation trick. `this.router.navigate(\`home/contract-view/${yourIdVariable}\`)`, but I think @weagle08's answer is more maintainable.

Answer (score 39):

preferred solution would be to use your named routes that you have configured in the router.

```
this.router.navigateToRoute('contract-view', {id: 10});
```

Comment: @weagle08 - Can you give an example of how? If you tried to navigate to the child route 'detail' in the fragment 'users/:id/detail' what would you expect to call navigateToRoute with? Presumably you'd have to call it on the child router for any chance of it working, which isn't great.

Comment: That's exactly what I did: call it from the child router. What is wrong with this approach that is being alluded to above?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @valichek,
Just had to make it `this.router.navigate('/home/contract-view/10')` for it to work. That extra `/` at the beginning made difference.